# rustc error using cargo build during compiling a project

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, mingw-w64

I have been learning for a few days the Rust language, I was writing the guessing game from the book of Rust and when I added the rand crate the code blows up and cargo didn't work for build the project.
The error message that I get:

```
   Compiling guessing_game v0.1.0 (C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game)
error: linking with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--dynamicbase" "-Wl,--disable-auto-image-base" "-m64" "-Wl,--high-entropy-va" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsbegin.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustcUsFK5k\\symbols.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.18kzraemhbsni77x.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.18x2n66sdlvroo2s.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.2jumpmbqyxthbbwv.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.2rimi6o97ep9m0vo.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.2xvdgv2ldd1rvjjk.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.2y2cd32yi0fzh6kt.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.3m0id8ozabv7ecin.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.3mxxjxc4bbjhjug.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.4fsmc04oz23s0w17.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.4gd9dm1ketcsa1az.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.4j75at8upe4h1dxx.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.4zf7un4kxypy7b6g.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.539xviday9wh32qu.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.592xg6iq0netggcp.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.5ggtdqlyp3a13qv1.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.d5l62waq46jed7m.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.4obr3dsz9dbkamgi.rcgu.o" "-L" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps" "-L" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\librand-7fbc8a5de9188078.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\librand_chacha-074241c5024a9c57.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\libppv_lite86-02511fdafde70359.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\librand_core-30181b09e6c6a646.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\libgetrandom-25ce142b63d47c1b.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\libcfg_if-e83ed72efe2719ee.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd-c39a33301a990d4c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-cca52022a9e303e0.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libobject-87ab4ba6115beae7.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libmemchr-5cb7fa9a12663885.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libaddr2line-63721decd0530f88.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libgimli-f46ca0e8336ae9ce.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_demangle-eb7f3864ed6b2a68.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd_detect-7a1913f37e63e841.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libhashbrown-bc9416be95f71206.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-583427bdf1f371c2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libminiz_oxide-cda0273dfc900176.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libadler-9e3a606a7eac348e.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libunwind-17b9231d7a9331b7.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcfg_if-dcab4b455bc920a1.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liblibc-9852f6e85c86dae7.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liballoc-2b83ab5495098fa8.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-baa2c1aeb27e5083.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcore-b5f8c582e1776c2a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-d13d1e3b0b541614.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lbcrypt" "-ladvapi32" "-lkernel32" "-ladvapi32" "-lbcrypt" "-lkernel32" "-lntdll" "-luserenv" "-lws2_32" "-lkernel32" "-lws2_32" "-lkernel32" "-lntdll" "-lkernel32" "-lgcc_eh" "-l:libpthread.a" "-lmsvcrt" "-lmingwex" "-lmingw32" "-lgcc" "-lmsvcrt" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-L" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-o" "C:\\Users\\criso\\Documents\\Proyectos de Programación\\Rust\\testPrograms\\guessing_game\\target\\debug\\deps\\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.exe" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-no-pie" "-nodefaultlibs" "C:\\Users\\criso\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsend.o"
  = note: C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.18kzraemhbsni77x.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.18x2n66sdlvroo2s.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.2jumpmbqyxthbbwv.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.2rimi6o97ep9m0vo.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.2xvdgv2ldd1rvjjk.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.2y2cd32yi0fzh6kt.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.3m0id8ozabv7ecin.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.3mxxjxc4bbjhjug.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.4fsmc04oz23s0w17.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.4gd9dm1ketcsa1az.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.4j75at8upe4h1dxx.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.4zf7un4kxypy7b6g.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.539xviday9wh32qu.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.592xg6iq0netggcp.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.5ggtdqlyp3a13qv1.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.d5l62waq46jed7m.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\guessing_game-fc4c7738ed2037e7.4obr3dsz9dbkamgi.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\librand-7fbc8a5de9188078.rlib: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\librand_chacha-074241c5024a9c57.rlib: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\libppv_lite86-02511fdafde70359.rlib: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\librand_core-30181b09e6c6a646.rlib: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\libgetrandom-25ce142b63d47c1b.rlib: No such file or directory
          C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\criso\Documents\Proyectos de Programación\Rust\testPrograms\guessing_game\target\debug\deps\libcfg_if-e83ed72efe2719ee.rlib: No such file or directory
          collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I talked with someone that told me that the problem is the MinGw linker and the solution is to install the VS build Tools for C++. But I really want to work with open source code, so I desire to find another solution.

Comment: Windows has notorious issues with folder or file names that include spaces. Try renaming "`Proyectos de Programación`" to e.g. "`Proyectos_de_Programacion`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the non-ASCII character "ó" in the path. Change it to "o" and you will succeed.

Using MinGW on Windows is no problem otherwise, even with paths containing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are running Microsoft Windows here and the supported solution is to set up Microsoft tool chain. The alternative way is to run all inside the windows Ubuntu subsystem where the standard Linux tool-chain works out of the box, this way you will only rely on opensource software.